# PHP: File writing issue

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I'm trying to make a function that writes a list of scores for players.

For example:

```
player_1 100 12 12 10
player_2 39 13 48 29
```

And when players beat (or do worse) than their previous scores, their score is over-written with the new score.

I've written a function that sort of works, but has multiple problems.

```
function write($player)
{
    global $logfile;
    $lines = file($logfile);
    foreach($lines as $i => $line)
    {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $line);
        $pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
        if( $pieces[0] == $player->name )  //found name
        {   
            trim($lines[$i]);
            unset($lines[$i]);  //remove the old player data
            $lines[$i] = "{$player->name} {$player->lvl} {$player->exp} {$player->mana} \n"; //write the new score
            $fp = fopen($logfile,'a');
            fwrite($fp,$lines[$i]);
            $found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) //record a new player whose score isn't in the file
    {
        $fp = fopen($logfile,'a');
        $newp = "$player->name $player->lvl $player->exp $player->mana \n";
        fwrite($fp, $newp); 
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The file just appends the new score and doesn't overwrite the previous score. Could someone point out my errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us see the reason why it duplicates the record. `$lines` is an array in which you are updating the record of the specific player. But after updating the record, you are appending it to the file (using "a" mode) and therefore duplicating the entry of that player.

The idea should be to update that record in the file. And with your logic, the best thing is to rewrite `$lines` to the file. Since `$lines` will always contain the updated entry, it makes sense.

Now coming to the logic where you are making an entry for a new player. There is nothing wrong in that logic but it could be improved by appending the new entry to `$lines` instead of writing to the file.

Here is the updated code. Please note that I've removed lines that weren't needed.

```
function write($player) {
    global $logfile;
    $found = FALSE;
    $lines = file($logfile);
    foreach($lines as $i => $line) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $line);
        $pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
        if( $pieces[0] == $player->name ) {  //found name
            $lines[$i] = "{$player->name} {$player->lvl} {$player->exp} {$player->mana} \n"; //write the new score
            $found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found) { //record a new player whose score isn't in the file
        $lines[] = "$player->name $player->lvl $player->exp $player->mana \n";
    }

    file_put_contents($logfile, $lines);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
$fp = fopen($logfile,'w');
```

into

```
$fp = fopen($logfile,'a');
```

in your

```
if( $pieces[0] == $player->name ) ...
```

[PHP.fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) file open modes ;)

**EDIT**
You can override your player entry by putting the `fwrite()` after foreach loop by overriding the whole file with **joined** lines (this may cause performace issues).

Or

Try to loop line by line using `fgets()` and then if you will find the right match use `fseek()` to the previous line and override it ;)

[fgets()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) [fseek()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

**SECOND EDIT**

```
<?php

$find = 'player_1';

$h = fopen('play.txt','r+');
$prev_pos = 0;
while(($line = fgets($h, 4096)) !== false){
    $parts = explode(' ', $line);

    if($parts[0] == $find) {
        fseek($h, $prev_pos);
        fwrite($h, "player_222 12 22 411");
        break;
    }
    $prev_pos = ftell($h);
}

fclose($h);

?>
```

Code sample as requested ;) The idea is to save previous line position and then use it to `fseek` and override. I'm not sure if the `fwrite` will work well on all enviroments without `PHP_EOL` at the end-of-line, but on mine it's fine.

Comment: yes, I have already tried that but it doesn't seem to overwrite the previous entry

Comment: I'll improve my answer ;) give me a sec

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm still having problems understanding fgets though, would you mind writing how it should be done (If it isn't too much work)

Comment: Thanks :) However, it still only appends to the file like: http://pastebin.com/pLxCG4r1 and does not overwrite the existing data.

Comment: @dukevin sorry, I was cleaning some debug data and I've deleted too much, now it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Is this code run on a web server with many users accessing at the same time?

If it is, imagine what happens when one user has just opened the file for writing, the file is emptied, and another opens it for reading before the first one has finished writing the data.

A partial solution is write to a temp file and rename the temp as the original when you are done. Rename is atomic, so the users will see either the original file or the new one and not something in between.

But youll still miss some updates. You could lock the file, meaning that when one person is writing another can't read. To do that you would use the flock function:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

The proper solution is **using a real database**. Sqlite for example is nice and simple: no external server processes or passwords...